# How to create a random shuffle from 2D array

Tags: arrays, random, multidimensional-array, shuffle

Im trying to create a random function from a given 2d array. The code should be able to shuffle cards based on information in array.

```
string DeckCards [6][6] = ///determine size of deck //deck1
{

    {"1A", "1B", "1C", "1D", "2A", "2B"},
    {"2C", "2D", "3A", "3B", "3C", "3D"},
    {"4A", "4B", "4C", "4D", "1A", "1B"},
    {"1C", "1D", "2A", "2B", "2C", "2D"},
    {"3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", "4A", "4B"},
    {"4C", "4D", "  ", "  ", "  ", "  "}

};

void randomize(string DeckCards[6][6],int n)
{
    srand( time(NULL) );
    for(int i = n-1; i > 6; i--)
    {
        int j = rand() %(4+1);
        swap(&DeckCards[i],[j]);
    }
}
```

the error is too large to include

Comment: You should really post the error, especially the first and last 10 lines.

Comment: Does it fail at compile time or run time? What is the code for `swap`?  What language is this?  What do you suspect is wrong?  Your declaration for randomize seems suspect and you might want to start there.

Comment: language: c++. error: Z:\CS 250\assignment5\Assg5_imason.cpp|289|warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]|

Comment: error: Z:\CS 250\assignment5\Assg5_imason.cpp|289|error: no matching function for call to 'swap(std::string (*)[6], randomize(std::string (*)[6], int)::__lambda0)'|

Comment: error: Z:\CS 250\assignment5\Assg5_imason.cpp||In function 'void randomize(std::string (*)[6], int)':|

Comment: It looks like your errors are saying that, at least minimally, you need to write a function for `swap`.